# How to create a form where the information on the XSN file cannot be changed after sent or saved?

Tags: infopath, permissions, data

Can I create a form where all data become static after saved or sent, and not available to be alteration on the filled data for the creator or anyone else either?

Besides, all non filled fields must remain avaiable for other users to fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this by having a status field associated with the form. With a form submit action, I set this field to submitted. Then on the fields, I have formatting rules that if the status field is submitted, the fields are read only.

Comment: How to set fields as read only with rules?
Do you set a rule for each field?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to create a formatting rule for each field that if statuscolumn = submitted, make the field read only. Fortunately InfoPath allows you to copy and paste rules.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use a rule on form load that switches views if statuscolumn = submitted. The second view can contain the read-only controls, or the data displayed using calculated value controls, or not show the data at all.

Answer (score 0):

I used a rule to save a state in a button. With a hidden field I set a rule to disable the controls whenever the field is not empity. So, when the hidden field receive any value, that cames previously set form the click of the "save" button, all the fields I want to remain not editalde anymore, can't be changed any further.
And I still can extract theier values to be displayed in columns in SharePoint. 
Do you think I can have any problems with this method?